# Is it a good idea to use lambda expression instead of delegates?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, lambda

**Lambda expression** can used instead of **delegates**, I'm not sure that it is a good way,I think it is more handy than delegates but I'm not sure that it is a good idea.

Is it a good idea to use **lambda expression** instead of **delegates**?

Comment: Why? Why do you think lambdas are not "a good way" or not "a good idea"?

Comment: You have an **interesting** use of **formatting**, like I somehow lack **reading comprehension**.

Comment: It depends on the case. Don't you have an example where both ways make sense and where you are not sure which is better?

Comment: @Stefan, there is no specific exaple in my mind, I just work onWeb Applications and I addicted using lambda expression, I really afraid that overusing them face my application with an issue, that's why I asked this question.

Comment: I don't really understand the question; it's a bit like asking "which is a better pet, a dog or a mammal?"  Well, a dog is a mammal, so that's not really a choice. Lambda expressions are used because they are convertible to delegates, so asking which is better doesn't really present a choice; if you're using lambdas, you're already using delegates. Can you ask the question such that there's a clear choice?

Comment: Do you mean is it better to use the lambda syntax for an anonymous method than the old C# 2 syntax?

Comment: @Eric: I think that's what he means. It's what I got from the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From a compiler perspective it makes no difference.

From a developer perspective lamba expressions improve readability in most cases.

Answer (score 8):

Write code for yourself and other developers, not for your computer.

If the lambda is easier to understand in your case, it's a good choice.

Most lambda-expressions will be compiled to delegates anyway. (Excluding expression trees)

Answer (score 4):

You can create a delegate instance in several different ways:

- Using C# 3 lambda expression:

  ```
  Func<int> getFive = () => 5;
  ```
- Using the C# 2 anonymous method syntax:

  ```
  Func<int> getFive = delegate { return 5 };
  ```
- Using non-anonymous method (available since C# 1):

  ```
  int GetFive()
  {
      return 5;
  }
  …
  Func<int> getFive = GetFive;
  ```

I think each of these has its uses.

The `delegate { }` syntax has the advantage that you don't have to declare the parameters if you don't need them.

Lambda expressions are very succinct and can be translated to expressions instead of delegates, which is very useful for LINQ-to-some-DB, and means you can use the same syntax for querying in-memory structures and databases.

Using non-anonymous methods means you can easily reuse them and is also suitable for long methods.

All the cases above are translated to equivalent code. The only difference is whether the method is visible to you.

Both lambda expressions and anonymous methods can also be closures, i.e. they can capture local variables.

Answer (score 1):

`yes`. you can do delegates by `lambda` and reduce number of lines of code and make code readable

Comment: [Lambada](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8mz9uOvFQA)? Haven't heard that in a while.

Comment: I know that I can do this, I amcurrently do this, I asked that is it a good idea? I think it may reduce performance or cause to another problem.

Comment: @Nasser Hadjloo no performance problem. for compiler both are same